# Changing CSS of one element based on another element focus/active state

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple bootstrap input group inside a form element, like this:

```
<form>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control home-search-input" placeholder="Recipient's username">
     <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary home-search-btn" type="button" id="button-addon2">Button</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I want when I manipulate the input element based on :focus and :active CSS pseudo classes, it changes the input element, but doesn't change the button addon.

Some of my css looks like this:

```
.home-search-input {
  border-right: 0;
  background-clip: border-box !important;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  transition: box-shadow ease-in-out .2s;
}

  .home-search-input:focus, .home-search-input:active {
    outline: 0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-bottom-color: none;
    background: #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(65,69, 73, 0.3),
                0 1px 3px 1px rgba(65,69, 73, 0.15) !important;
    border-right:none;
    border-color: #ced4da;
  }

.home-search-btn {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  padding: 6px 12px !important;
  /* border-radius: 23.79px 23.79px 23.79px 23.79px; */
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-left: none;
}
```

How do I get the .home-search-btn to also apply box shadow and background color changes based on .home-search-input:focus, .home-search-input:active?

Comment: Where are `.home-search-btn` and `.home-search-input` in your HTML?

Comment: see updated post

Comment: Where are these classes used **in your HTML**?

Comment: sir, they are in the classes of the html. See the updated post.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/zq264578/) is the HTML in your post. It never uses any of the above classes.

Comment: They are LITERALLY in the html you just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [CSS combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Put this in your code:

```
.home-search-input:focus ~ .input-group-append > button {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(65,69, 73, 0.3), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(65,69, 73, 0.15) !important;
  background-color: red;
}
```

This (in words) means *When input is focused, change button that is in (`>` sign) .input group that is next to (`~` sign) input*

This would be your code:

```css
.home-search-input {
  border-right: 0;
  background-clip: border-box !important;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  transition: box-shadow ease-in-out .2s;
}

.home-search-input:focus,
.home-search-input:active,
{
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(65, 69, 73, 0.3), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(65, 69, 73, 0.15);
}

.home-search-input:focus~.input-group-append>button,
.home-search-input:active~.input-group-append>button {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(65, 69, 73, 0.3), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(65, 69, 73, 0.15);
}

.home-search-btn {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  padding: 6px 12px !important;
  /* border-radius: 23.79px 23.79px 23.79px 23.79px; */
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control home-search-input" placeholder="Recipient's username">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary home-search-btn" type="button" id="button-addon2">Button</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is close, there's just a slight delay when I click on the input from the input changing state to the button (the button changing background and box shadow lags the input)

Comment: I fixed the lag by adding a transition delay on the input.

Comment: @J.G.Sable glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.home-search-input:active + .input-group-append .home-search-btn,
.home-search-input:focus + .input-group-append .home-search-btn {
    background: #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(65,69, 73, 0.3),
                0 1px 3px 1px rgba(65,69, 73, 0.15) !important;
}
```